# Is there any value in embedding hyperlinks in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, seo, adobe, acrobat

My company has given me a PDF that's already been mastered, packaged, etc. but of course the one thing they didn't do is add a linking hotspot over the 2" square ad space that they've set out for themselves.  I have a hard time imagining people click links in PDFs with any regularity but can't find any knowledge to back that up.  Are there any benefits to search? As of now the only place this linked version will exist is on the site that the ad itself links to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen anything definitive that says search engines parse PDFs for links or if they help SEO or not. But Google does read and index PDFs, and some flash as well, so those links are probably being seen by them. If I were to speculate about this I would say those links do have some SEO value. All of the rules would apply to it such as anchor text, link popularity (probably to the PDF document), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Most people seem to regard PDF as "Printable Document File" rather than "Portable Document Format".  If the document has the website address on it, that is sufficient.